# Incorrect replacement of strings in R

Tags: r, string, time, replace, stringr

I need to replace awkward strings in R, specifically the times that are in a weird format. The data looks like this:

```
      Date |    Time | AmbientTemp
2000-01-01 | 11:00 a |          25
2000-01-01 | 11:30 a |        25.5 
2000-01-01 | 11:00 p |          20
2000-01-01 | 11:30 p |        19.5
```

The `a` and `p` mean AM and PM respectively (obviously).

`lubridate` and `base` R cannot convert these dates to a correct format. Thus, I turned to the cumbersome `str_replace_all` function (from package `stringr`) to convert ALL my times in a large dataframe: >130000 records.

Example functions:

```
uploadDat$Time = str_replace_all(uploadDat$Time,"11:00 a","11:00")
uploadDat$Time = str_replace_all(uploadDat$Time,"11:00 p","23:00")
```

I changed the class of the times using `as.character()` before applying `stringr`'s functions.

The result is perfect except for the 11'o clock times (like above) that are converted as follow:

```
      Date |   Time | AmbientTemp
2000-01-01 | 101:00 |          25
2000-01-01 | 101:30 |        25.5 
2000-01-01 | 113:30 |          20
2000-01-01 | 113:30 |        19.5
```

**Why are these specific times converted incorrectly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `paste` `"m"` at the end of time, convert it into `POSIXct`

```
format(as.POSIXct(paste0(df$Time, "m"), format = "%I:%M %p"), "%T")
#[1] "11:00:00" "11:30:00" "23:00:00" "23:30:00"
```